# How get device's ip those connected to local network in Windows IoT Core/UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I have installed windows iot core in raspberry pi. I connected to local network I need all device's ip and host-name connected to same network. My main goal is to find all other raspberry pi list connected to same network.

Comment: this is not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/iotdashboard) to detect all the devices connected in the network which running with Windows IoT Core.In "My Devices" tab, it lists the name,type,ip, and OS version of all detected devices. Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard is the best way to list and connect your Windows 10 IoT Core devices, all from your PC.